# Is there way to load xgb native model into spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, xgboost

Here is my scenario:
I train XGB model with single machine, and want to load it into spark to process data. Is there a way to do it?

The official document give a way to train xgb model with spark, and convert it into native model. But it doesn't give the reverse direction.

`XGBoostClassificationModel.load` only supports passing a spark-version xgb model path, if passing a path of native model, it will report error.

According to github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3689 , the step is 1, read native booster, 2, construct Model

github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3689 only resolves 2 construct model, but I can't find a way read native booster with xgboost-spark 1.0.0

I guess the way to load native booster can be divided into 2 steps:

1. load native booster
2. create XGBModel

```
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.XGBoost
val booster = XGBoost.loadModel(nativeBoostPath)
// create a bridge class according to github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3689
val model = new XGBoostClassificationModelBridge("1",2, booster) // this will report error
```

But the 2nd step report error

Comment: This is possible. You should implement your own model loader class in Scala. Refer to this issue: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3689.

Comment: Thanks, @PavelFilatov, the link is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old, but I ran across the same thing when trying to load my native XGBoost model trained in Python over in Spark/Scala.

This seems to work for the bridge class:

```
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.Booster
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoostClassificationModel

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor

class XGBoostClassificationModelBridge(uid: String, numClasses: Int, _booster: Booster) {
  val constructor: Constructor[XGBoostClassificationModel] = classOf[XGBoostClassificationModel].getDeclaredConstructor(classOf[String], classOf[Int], classOf[Booster])
  constructor.setAccessible(true)
  val xgbClassificationModel: XGBoostClassificationModel = constructor.newInstance(uid, Int.box(numClasses), _booster)
}
```

I was then able to use it something like this:

```
val booster = XGBoost.loadModel("/path/to/model.xgb")
val bridge = new XGBoostClassificationModelBridge(null, 20, booster)
val classifier = bridge.xgbClassificationModel

// if you need params:
classifier.set(classifier.objective, "multi:softprob")
classifier.set(classifier.missing, 0f)
```

Trying to set the params directly on the Booster object did not seem to work.